# cmake link library of a target based on the result from executing another target

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to use the contents of a file generated from running a target in order to define some libraries that will be linked against another target.

This would be something like:

```
add_executable(generator zoot.cpp)

get_property(GEN_LOCATION TARGET generator PROPERTY LOCATION)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT libInfo.txt
                   COMMAND ${GEN_LOCATION}
                   DEPENDS someOtherFile.txt)

add_custom_target(lib_info_generator ALL
                  DEPENDS libInfo.txt someOtherFile.txt)

add_dependencies(lib_info_generator generator)

add_executable(final_target hi.cpp)

file(STRINGS "libInfo.txt" MY_LIB)

if(MY_LIB STREQUAL "lib1")
  target_link_libraries(final_target lib1)
else()
  target_link_libraries(final_target lib2)
endif()
```

This does not work because libInfo.txt won't exist until the target lib_info_generator is performed.

Is there a way to implement this in CMake?

Comment: You may try to set property GENERATED for file libInfo.txt, but i think that this does not helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to CMake and I'm just guessing, but you could try to force build order by setting

```
add_dependencies(final_target lib_info_generator)
```

@Alexey: According to CMake documentation outputs from custom commands get automatically property GENERATED set. So that wouldn't change the situation.